# File exists not working when path specified

Tags: java, macos, file, filepath, java-io

On a mac, osx, when the I do:

```
File file = new File("ah/myfile.text");
```

I can do:

```
file.getParent()
```

I get

```
ah
```

but if I do

```
file.exists()
```

I get false returned.

Why?

Comment: Try printing the canonical path of the file.  I bet it does not point to where you thought it did.

Comment: Print the path.  Also, the parent directory exists, but the file itself doesn't.  Meaning folder "ah" exists, but "myfile.text" doesn't (at least in the directory your File class is pointing at).

Comment: The `File` represents a String path, not an actual file system file. Java 7's NIO API is more obvious about this with the new class `Path`. Consider using that

Comment: After you have created the `Path`, use `Files.createFile` to create a new file there or throw if it can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getParent () just parses given path and removes the last section aftwr last slash. However exists () performs a real check. I gess that yor file indeed does not exist in this location. To check your current directory do new File(".").getAbsolutePath () and modify your path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("ah/myfile.text");

System.out.println(file.getParent());
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

Output:

```
ah
false
```

I get the same result. Get parent must parse the path as a string, even if it the file and/or the directory does not exist.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: Andrew- Will do! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A `File` does not necessary have to exist. It could be a reference to a file already on the system, or a file which can potentially be on the system.

What you are saying is that you have a path to a (potential) file at `ah/myfile.text`, but it could be that neither the file nor the parent directory exists yet. Its parent is still `ah/` though.

You can also check if the parent exists by doing `file.getParentFile().exists();`